# Clion cannot link external libraries but Visual Studio works with same CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c, cmake, clion

My `CMakeList.txt` is below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.2)
set(PROJECT_NAME learnGL)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)


# ------------#
#    GLFW3    #
# ------------#
set(GLFW3_DIR "******/ExternalLabs/GLFW3")
set(GLFW3_LIBRARIES ${GLFW3_DIR}/lib)
set(GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GLFW3_DIR}/include)
set(GLFW3 ${GLFW3_LIBRARIES}/glfw3.lib)
include_directories(${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIRS})


# ------------#
#     GLAD    #
# ------------#
set(GLAD_DIR "******/ExternalLabs/GLAD")
set(GLAD_SRC_DIR ${GLAD_DIR}/src)
set(GLAD_INC_DIR ${GLAD_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${GLAD_INC_DIR})


# ------------#
#   OpenGL    #
# ------------#
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )


# -----------------------#
#       target           #
# -----------------------#
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c ${GLAD_SRC_DIR}/glad.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLFW3} )
```

Here `******/ExternalLibs` is the directory of my external libraries which structures always is like below:

```
<LibraryName>
  |__ include
  |__ lib
  |__ src
```

`include` is the header file directory, and `lib` is the directory where the `*.lib` files are located.

Another one, my project is very simple:

```
learnGL
  |__ CMakeLists.txt
  |__ main.c
```

This project's CmakeList.txt file works in Visual Studio 2022, but not in CLion 2021.2 with errors like `unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main`.

So why and How to solve this problem? Thnx.

Comment: This is not C++ right, so can you remove the C++ tag?

Comment: Is your CLion configured to use MSVC compiler for compilation?

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes, it is.

Comment: Your CMakeLists.txt has `ExternalLabs` instead of  `ExternalLibs` - is it a typo which is probably causing this linker issues?